# How can I parse Jupiter Aggregator instructions?

Tags: instructions, jupiter

I'm trying to decode/parse these instructions and visualise some data to the user

[image]

Tried with `decodeInstruction` from `@solana/spl-token` but so unsucuessfull any idea how to parse it?

Answer (score 2):

These are instructions for a Jupiter Aggregator program. Use Jupiter's [instruction parser](https://github.com/jup-ag/instruction-parser).